# e.parameter Google Apps Script tutorial undefined errer

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to go through the UI service tutorial with the following code at this [link][1]: When I run it, I get an error stating that the parameter in e.parameter.userName is undefined. I changed the handler from app.createServerClickHandler to app.createServerHandler as the prior one shows deprecated. How do I get past this? Is the tutorial wrong or misleading me someway? I looked and looked and just finally copy and pasted the code but still same error.

```
unction doGet(e) {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID_GOES_HERE);
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('New app');

  // Create the entry form, a 3 x 2 grid with text boxes for name, age, and city that is then added to a vertical panel
  var grid = app.createGrid(3, 2);
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Name:'));
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('userName').setId('userName'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Age:'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('age').setId('age'));
  grid.setWidget(2, 0, app.createLabel('City'));
  grid.setWidget(2, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('city').setId('city'));

  // Create a vertical panel and add the grid to the panel
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  panel.add(grid);

  // Here's where this script diverges from the previous script.
  // We create a horizontal panel called buttonPanel to hold two buttons, one for submitting the contents of the form
  // to the Spreadsheet, the other to close the form.

  var buttonPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();

  // Two buttons get added to buttonPanel: button (for submits) and closeButton (for closing the form)
  // For the submit button we create a server click handler submitHandler and pass submitHandler to the button as a click handler.
  // the function submit gets called when the submit button is clicked.
  var button = app.createButton('submit');
  var submitHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('submit');
  submitHandler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  button.addClickHandler(submitHandler);
  buttonPanel.add(button);

  // For the close button, we create a server click handler closeHandler and pass closeHandler to the close button as a click handler.
  // The function close is called when the close button is clicked.
  var closeButton = app.createButton('close');
  var closeHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('close');
  closeButton.addClickHandler(closeHandler);
  buttonPanel.add(closeButton);


  // Create label called statusLabel and make it invisible; add buttonPanel and statusLabel to the main display panel.
  var statusLabel = app.createLabel().setId('status').setVisible(false);
  panel.add(statusLabel);

  panel.add(buttonPanel);

  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

// Close everything return when the close button is clicked
function close() {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  // The following line is REQUIRED for the widget to actually close.
  return app;
}

// function called when submit button is clicked
function submit(e) {

  // Write the data in the text boxes back to the Spreadsheet
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID_GOES_HERE);
  var lastRow = doc.getLastRow();
  var cell = doc.getRange('a1').offset(lastRow, 0);
  cell.setValue(e.parameter.userName);
  cell.offset(0, 1).setValue(e.parameter.age);
  cell.offset(0, 2).setValue(e.parameter.city);

  // Clear the values from the text boxes so that new values can be entered
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('userName').setValue('');
  app.getElementById('age').setValue('');
  app.getElementById('city').setValue('');
  // Make the status line visible and tell the user the possible actions
  app.getElementById('status').setVisible(true).setText('User ' + e.parameter.userName + ' entered.' +
  'To add another, type in the information and click submit. To exit, click close.');
  return app;
}​


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service#doGetParams
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably testing this script the wrong way...

Are you using the .dev url to test your code ?

There are actually 2 urls for each webapp :
The one shown as an url for the app (ending with .exec ) and the **test url** that returns **the latest saved version** of your script and that you have to use to test the code "as it is" at the moment you edit / save it.

The .exec version corresponds to the version you choose  in the deployment window as illustrated below.
[image]

the other issue in this code is the `close function` , in a deployed webapp the app will never close nor hide this way... it works only when embedded in a document (or spreadsheet etc) not in a standalone app.

What you can eventually to to 'simulate' a 'close' is to make the grid content invisible but that's about all...